# Rounded Textured Segmented control style deprecated in OSX 10.7? What should I use?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I'm getting this warning message when I try using "Segmented control" with style "Rounded Textured".

It is the default style in Interface Builder, so I wonder why is it complaining?

If I set to any other style, the warning goes away. But I want to use this style, so that it matches other controls in the task bar.

OSX10.7 / XCode 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about "automatic"? That's what's always looking good for me.

Comment: hmm.. the look is identical to 'rounded textured' so that's good. strange IB defaults to a deprecated value... thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, IB is not always straight-edge ;)

Comment: I'm also getting the same silly error, except now it says Capsule segmented control style is deprecated... This is exactly the style that finder in 10.7 itself uses. here is the warning http://cl.ly/D1en, anybody has an idea how to surppress or fix it?

Comment: The automatic style actually doesn't look native on 10.7, capsule does though, it's all very strange.

Comment: The automatic with Xcode 4.3 looks like the "Rounded" aqua buttons, not good.

Comment: @valexa I tried Textured Square and it seems like a good enough replacement of Textured Round.

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit this issue and the suggested fix of using "Automatic" doesn't work for me. I managed to fix it by setting the Deployment Target of the .xib to 10.6. My project's target deployment is already 10.6, so it should have been anyway.

Don't forget to unset "Use Auto Layout" if you actually want to run your App on 10.6, else it will throw an exception:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with Auto Layout unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: @migs647 No, I don't think so.  Try the other textured style, which doesn't generate a deprecation warning and looks pretty similar to me...

Comment: @ChuckH you should make "Textured Square" an answer. Automatic isn't an option these days and "Textured Square" is the only style that looks good, other styles are ugly or deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Textured Square" worked best for me.

Comment: As @BradGoss reminded me that this is the only style that really looks acceptable.  All of the other styles are ugly or deprecated.