# Deprecated: Rounded Textured Segmented Control

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How to get rid of warnings "Deprecated: Rounded Textured Segmented Control style on Mac OS X versions 10.7 and later" in cocoa project targeted for 10.7 & greater.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533285/rounded-textured-segmented-control-style-deprecated-in-osx-10-7-what-should-i-u

Comment: Yes.. But there is no correct solution given for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off "Deprecated" warnings by going to Project or Target settings and looking for the setting that has "Deprecated" in the title.  It'll look something like this:

[image: Deprecated Warnings Turn Off]

Of course, I need to warn you ***against*** doing this.  API's that are deprecated can start working unexpectedly in future versions of MacOS or worse, be pulled altogether (in which case your app would completely crash).  It'd be better to look at the alternatives for your control, to get rid of those warnings to begin with.